# Can't connect to local MySQL, issue with socket

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, dump

I try to make a backup of database with script in my django project.

Here is my code:

```
DUMPFILE = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'backup', '%s.mysql.gz' % settings.DATABASE_NAME)
res = commands.getoutput('mysqldump -p%s %s | gzip > %s' % (settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD, settings.DATABASE_NAME, DUMPFILE))
print res

DUMPFILE = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'backup', 'project_next.mysql.gz')
res = commands.getoutput('mysqldump -p%s project | gzip > %s' % (settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD, DUMPFILE))
print res
```

But I got an error:

```
Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")"
```

Please for help with this.

Comment: Looks like mysql server is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Jens comment your mysql server is stopped.
you can check it's status by this line:

```
service mysqld status
```

for start mysql server use:

```
service mysqld start
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I get an error: `Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect`

Comment: use this line in your terminal : sudo mysql -uroot -p